# Is omnisharp Server similar to IIS express

Tags: omnisharp

Is omnisharp server similar to IIS express? Let's say I have a project folder which has only html files, I start the ominisharp server through atom text editor. It gets started and says listening at port xxxx

If I browse localhost://xxxx/index.html will it serve that file?

I am newbie please clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the point of the Omnisharp server is not to be a general purpose web server - it's to act as a *service*. Think of it as an "IDE service" that just happens to exposed itself over HTTP, as that's the easiest way for many clients to talk to a service.

Unless you need to integrate something with Omnisharp yourself (i.e. writing code to be a client), you can probably just think of it as a plugin for whatever you're using. (In most cases there will be an *actual* plugin, which then talks to Omnisharp.)